# Can't find HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() in WP7 Project

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, xna

I'm trying to send a GET request using HttpWebRequest.
I've found a lot of examples all over the web (for example, [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/cs-CZ/csharplanguage/thread/6e02f731-bc2e-4d85-835c-ac885d2e4ee5/)...just go down to the `Scrape()` method). They all basically do the same thing:

Create a `HttpWebRequest` object by using WebRequest.Create(URL) and casting it to `HttpWebRequest`, then getting the response by using the `GetResponse()` method from `HttpWebRequest`.

Thing is, `GetResponse()` doesn't seem to exist in either `HttpWebRequest` or `WebRequest` (which is its base class). My only option is to use `BeginGetResponse()`.

The only thing I found is that `GetResponse()` is synchronous, while `BeginGetResponse()` is asynchronous, and that Silverlight only allows the asynchronous one. Well, that doesn't help me at all, since the whole thing is an XNA project, and this is a simple C# class I created inside.
Well to be more accurate, this is a Windows Phone game, created in XNA 4.0

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest; 
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader( 
         webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why I don't have `GetResponse()`?

Comment: Is this for Windows Phone? If it is, then requests are still asynchronous only.

Comment: I've never had a problem. [See GetResponse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) -- but I only use "normal" .NET. Note any XNA differences.

Comment: Aaaah, I see. Yep, it's WP7. I just edited my question and added that, before I noticed your answer. Hehe, wish i knew that 2 hours ago. That would've definitely saved me the headache. Thanks for the help

Comment: @keyboardP You should post it as an answer so it can be accepted ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

XNA 4 for Windows Phone 7 can only make asynchronous calls. You might find the code at the bottom of [this post](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/54886/333680.aspx) helpful as well.

Code from that post:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    string webServiceAddress = @"http://localhost/service/service1.asmx";           
    string methodName = "HelloWorld";

    string webServiceMethodUri = string.Format("{0}/{1}", webServiceAddress, methodName);

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(webServiceMethodUri);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(Response_Completed, httpWebRequest);

    base.Initialize();
 }

 void Response_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
 {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string xml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
             reader.MoveToContent();
             reader.GetAttribute(0);
             reader.MoveToContent();
             message = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nice, it's exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Asahi Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the link in the post (http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/54886/333680.aspx)

Comment: Question... What does the base.initialise do (it doesn't have to exist right)? And does BeginGetResponse lock the thread of will base.initialise be executed imidiately