# Where Did WebRequest.GetResponse go?

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I am trying to access a web API using an HttpWebRequest in C#. However, whenever I attempt to use the method GetResponse I get an error that the method does not exist.

However it is clearly defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) that GetResponse should work.

I have done something almost identical to this on a different app. The code for that app was written on a different machine. Still, is it possible to perform a GetResponse without having to muck with threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is caused because you're on Silverlight which has a subset of the actual framework. You should use the async methodsof the GetResponse. It seems it's duplicated on this post [Can't find HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() in WP7 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971866/cant-find-httpwebrequest-getresponse-in-wp7-project)

Answer (score -1):

[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) are not available when your are develop apps for WP7. You need to use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and there only the async methods.