# Trouble using GetResponse in C# for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When I use

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I get an error message stating that

```
'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no   extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I've added the following reference ,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp23.Resources;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
```

Have I missed out something??
Or what should I do, to make this work properly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() in WP7 Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971866/cant-find-httpwebrequest-getresponse-in-wp7-project)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In windows phone you need to do every action that can take longer as 50ms async. Since a webrequest can take longer, microsoft removed the sync method from the class. Instead you need to use the async method:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new System.Uri("http://www.google.com"));
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request); 

private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    using(HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //execute UI stuff on UI thread.
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBlockResults.Text = results);
        }
    }
}
```